# We align $N$ persons including persons A and B, what is the probability that they sit next to each other?

Tags: probability

We align $N$ persons including person A and B in a row, what is the probability that A and B sit next to each other?

I can't find the right equation for this one, so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would help me a lot.

Thank you

Comment: HINT : Tie A and B together and consider them as a singe person to count the cases where they sit together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1(A is at the end):
A at the and probability is $\frac{2}{n}$. To choose B, there is one available slot, next to A is $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Case 2(A is at the middle):
A at the middle probability is $\frac{n-2}{n}$. To choose B, there is two available slots, next to A is $\frac{2}{n-1}$

Final:
$\frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n}\frac{2}{n-1} = \frac{2+2n-4}{n(n-1)} = \frac{2n-2}{n(n-1)} = \frac{2}{n}$

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to consider just $A$ and $B$.

$N$ seats have $N-1$ combos for for 2 adjacent seats, against $\binom{N}{2}$ total combos

thus $Pr = \dfrac{(N-1)}{\dbinom{N}{2}} = \dfrac2N$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Seat person $A$ first.

Break into cases: Either person $A$ is sitting at an end, or person $A$ isn't sitting at an end.

Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: For adjacent seats ?

Comment: @trueblueanil if my hint was not clear enough, I'm saying you should first find the probability that $A$ is sitting on an end seat, then find the probability that $B$ is sitting in the only available adjacent seat.  Add this to the probability that $A$ is sitting in a center seat, then find the probability that $B$ is sitting in either of the seats next to $A$.  Yes "*for adjacent seats*."

Comment: Okay, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
If A and B are sitting together, we can consider them as a single entity.  Instead of n people, there will be n-1 people.