# Probability of two people sitting next to each other

Tags: probability

I know this question was asked here: [We align $N$ persons including persons A and B, what is the probability that they sit next to each other?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475031/we-align-n-persons-including-persons-a-and-b-what-is-the-probability-that-the) but I'm still confused.

You have N people, what is the probability that person A and person B will sit next to each other?  This is how I was thinking of it:

Event = person A and person B sitting next to each other

Total seating arrangements = N!

P(E) = $\frac{N(E)}{N}$

N(E) = $\binom{N}{1}\binom{1}{1}(N-2)!2!$

So:
P(E) = $\frac{\binom{N}{1}\binom{1}{1}(N-2)!2!}{N!}$ = $\frac{2}{N-1}$  which is wrong.

For the numerator - you are picking one person, out of N, for a random seat, then choosing one person out of one for the second seat.  You then need to permutate the remaining (N-2) people and finally permutate the two people who are sitting next to each other.

I'm close....

Answer (score 1):

You have to reserve two adjacent seats for person $A$ and person $B$.  That block of two adjacent seats must begin in one of the first $N - 1$ positions.  We can arrange person $A$ and person $B$ in the two seats we select in $2!$ ways and arrange the remaining $N - 2$ people in the remaining $N - 2$ seats in $(N - 2)!$ ways.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$(N - 1)2!(N - 2)! = 2(N - 1)!$$
Since there are $N!$ possible arrangements of the $N$ people, the probability that person $A$ and person $B$ sit in adjacent seats is
$$\frac{2(N - 1)!}{N!} = \frac{2}{N}$$
It looks like you failed to take into account that the two adjacent seats must begin in the first $N - 1$ positions.